# How to determine info. about machine on network

Tags: networking, ip

At my place of employment, each employee is given a range of ten IP addresses to use for his/her machines. I have the range xx.xx.6.1-xx.xx.6.10. My problem is I want to use xx.xx.6.6 but something else on the network is already occupying that address. This machine responds to ICMP but not to SSH or RDP. I would like to determine what operating system this machine is running (and possibly the kind of machine i.e server,desktop,switch,etc.) before going to my superiors about the issue. What is the best way to determine this information?

Oh and nslookup responds with this (blah.blah.blah.blah is our DNS server):

```
*** blah.blah.blah.blah can't find xx.xx.6.6: Non-existent domain
```

and tracert responds with this:

```
1   17 ms    8 ms    7 ms  xx.xx.6.6
Trace complete.
```

Comment: @Patrick, asking the same question in 20 different ways is a good thing. It means that the chances of someone finding the answer much, much higher. The number of times I've asked a question just to find a dupe where they used the term "NIC" instead of "Network Card". The different terminology meant that I couldn't find the answer. But now that my question is in the system, someone comes along and finds my question and gets the right answer. Everyone wins.

Comment: @Patrick: This one actually has an interesting twist - he has been assigned the use of that IP ( he has the range of 6.1-6.10 ) and someone else has pilfered it.  But to answer your question 2^32 ways

Comment: @everyone - removed my previous comments since I'm apparently not that funny (but I still think Zypher's response was great).

Comment: Thanks guys. turns out out it is a Cisco switch/router meaning my boss(es) probably put it there and forgot about it. You were all right so I gave the check to the first answer and upvoted everyone.

Comment: And for the record, I wasn't poking fun at Puddingfox - I was poking fun at myself and everyone else that quickly suggested the great and powerful nmap (which wasn't once mentioned in the actual question) - obviously my feelings are still hurt (wink wink).

Comment: I never saw the original comment but humor is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[nmap](http://nmap.org/) should give you all the info you need. There's a great Windows GUI versions for those like me who don't like to wade through command line options.

Comment: ... one min quicker than me

Comment: If you're looking for a Gui then use zenmap.  Works on Linux, Windows, and OSX

Comment: Yeah Zenmap is the one I've got. It's great.

Answer (score 3):

From windows **nbtstat -a xx.xx.6.6** will give you the netbios name of the remote machine.

**arp -a** will give you the MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

`nmap -O xx.xx.6.6` may give you some ideas.  It's not 100% accurate though.

Answer (score 1):

Run nmap against it:

```
nmap -O -v xx.xx.6.6
```

And read up on nmap here:

http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html